# How to get an HTML tag of a container element without binding and change it background image Using VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am new in VueJS. Currently, I am facing some problem. In my Vue project I have a DIV which trigger a function on click:

```
<div
  class="product-thumbnails-image-container"
  data-lowsrc="{{asset('img/220x220.png')}}"
  style="background-image:url(img/products/thumb.jpg)"
  v-on:click="changeImage"
  data-lg-img="img/products/large.jpg"
  data-sm-img="img/products/image.jpg"
  data-thumb-img="img/products/thumb.jpg"
></div>
```

My VueJS instance looks like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    changeImage: function(evt) {
      if (evt) evt.preventDefault();
      // chage background image here
    }
  }
});
```

In Vue element container an HTML element is rendered after page load by a jQuery plugin. which is below:

```
<div
  id="zoom_01-lens"
  class="magnifier-lens"
  style="width: 208px; height: 208px; background: url("http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/products/anotherImage.jpg") -155px -28px no-repeat scroll; left: 154px; top: 27px;"
></div>
```

Since it is not present in my HTML file so I can't bind with it with the data model. So, how can I change the background image of `zoom_01-lens` when `changeImage()` function triggered?

Comment: You should bound background image url with single-quote.

Answer (score 1):

Vue may not play nicely with with JQuery plugins. Your plugins will interact with the DOM, but Vue can overwrite any part of the DOM any time it sees fit, potentially nuking any event listeners the plugins may depend on. You should really look for a Vue plugin that does what your JQuery plugin does.

If you want to try to make them live together, put your `changeImage()` function in global scope, outside Vue, where it has access to document. Then call it from Vue. This may work, but it's not very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Within your`changeImage()` you can change the background of `zoom_01-lens`.
Unsure if this is what you want, as with this solution you don't have an `onClick` function for your `zoom_01-lens`

In the below snippet I removed your local paths to assets.

```js
new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            
        },
        methods: {
            changeImage() {
                let element = document.querySelector('#zoom_01-lens');
                element.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
            }
        }
    })
```

```css
.product-thumbnails-image-container{
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.zoom_01-lens{
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
            <div class="product-thumbnails-image-container"  
            style="background-image:url(img/products/thumb.jpg)" 
            v-on:click="changeImage">click me</div>

            <div id="zoom_01-lens"
            class="magnifier-lens"
            style="width: 208px;
            height: 208px;
            background: url('http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/products/anotherImage.jpg') -155px -28px no-repeat scroll; left: 154px; top: 27px;"
            >This will change</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Is there any Vue Finding Mechanism? To retrieve Specific Children from App Root?